# Ruby wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

I'm trying to to create my getters and setters using `attr_accessor`. I want to assign a value to my variables.

Here is my code:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    attr_accessor :name
  end

  def initialize(age)
    attr_accessor :age
  end
end

person1 = Person.new
person1.name = "Andre"
person1.age  = 22
```

I get some trouble though. My error is:

```
q5.rb:6:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're trying to do:

```
class Person 
  attr_accessor :name, :age
end

person1 = Person.new
person1.name = "Andre"
person1.age  = 22
```

An *alternative* approach, for example, could be:

```
class Person 
  attr_accessor :name, :age

  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end
end

person1 = Person.new("Andre", 22)
```

The error you're seeing is because you defined (and then re-defined) an `initialize` method that is expecting one parameter:

```
def initialize(name)
```

and then tried to create an object without supplying a parameter:

```
person1 = Person.new
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll get accept your answer when the time limit is up

Comment: @Tiffx97 Note the indentation in this answer, two-spaces :)

Comment: One more question. When I try to print it out using "put" my respone is #<Person:0x00000000d2b068>

Comment: What do you expect `puts person1` to display? It's an instance of `Person`, so that's exactly what you see! If you go with the second approach (which I'd generally recommend), then you also see the instance variables: `#<Person:0x00007fcacb34ab00 @age=22, @name="Andre">`

Comment: If you want it to display something else, then you can define a custom `to_s` method on the class. But that's well beyond the scope of your original question :)